# Working directories of files used in Windows applications

Tags: windows, search, directory, absolute-path

Where does an application look when a file is searched for? Where is it created? It's rarely realistic to always specify the absolute path. E.g. I tried saving text files that were going to be used in a Visual Studio 2010 app in the local bin of the project solution, but always got a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually the folder it was called from. You can find it using `_getcwd`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Please define what you mean by "the folder it was called from".

Comment: Historically, the directory you were in when you called the program, i.e., `%CD%`. Nowadays, I believe it depends on the way the program is started. If, for instance, it is started using a link, it is typically the folder the program (.exe) is in. However, it can be changed in the properties of the link. I'm not sure what the default setting of VC is, though.

Comment: And what about when the process changes the working directory?

Comment: I see your point - you're absolutely right there. My assumption is that when someone deliberately changes the working directory, he knows what a working directory is. In that case, this question would most likely be obsolete.

Comment: In a console app, everything is based around the working directory. But it's not clear cut in a GUI app. Working directory gets messed up pretty good quite often.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative path, the path you supply is combined with the working directory of the process.

It's very hard to maintain control over the working directory of a GUI process. That's because GUI processes tend to be started in lots of different ways. What's more, file dialogs have a tendency to change working directory. Finally, the working directory is shared between all threads in the process, and can be changed by any thread. There are lots of pitfalls.

So in a GUI process I suggest that you never use relative paths. Or, if you do use relative paths, you convert them to absolute paths before using them. And perform that conversion against a well-defined root path.

Unless you are writing a portable app, you should not expect to be able to save to the directory which contains the executable file. On modern systems executable files are often located in read-only directories.

If you want to save user settings, save them at an appropriate location in the user's profile.

On the other hand, if you are wanting to read files, that you never modify, then it's reasonable to store them alongside the executable. But even in that case, open the file using a full absolute path. Create that path by combining the directory which contains the executable, with the relative path to the file.

So, to summarise, you said:

> It's rarely realistic to always specify the absolute path.

But I disagree. I would counter that using an absolute path is very often the best option. But you don't have to hard code the absolute path. You can, and should, create it at runtime.